# Any interest in a NYC-area meetup?

Tags: discussion, meetup

In the spirit of the [Stack Exchange meetups](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/stack-overflow-meetups-april-6/):

Who here is in the New York metro area? Who wants to meet and ride around?

The purpose of this would be to meet with our bikes and maybe have lunch or coffee. Any riding could be, oh, I don't know, maybe a ride through Central Park? Maybe on a Sunday in June? It'd be even more awesomesaucer if we could get a few of the NYC Stack Exchange employees there.

Is anybody in New York and could find a meeting place? It would have to be someplace we could meet and stash bikes. (I'd be open to the idea of meeting in New Jersey, maybe in Sandy Hook or at the shore, but let's keep it to places that can be reached by public transportation if at all possible.)

Discuss? Is this a good idea? Should this question be on Meta SO? In our chatroom with the crickets?

Comment: I fear the main problem is your basic "1500 users, 12 of whom live near New York" one. SE has 100's of 1000's of users. But I'm unlikely to go to any of the meetups so I'm probably not the right person to ask. I'm not even on the warm showers list any more.

Comment: There are many users who don't put their location in their profiles. Who was it that said something like, "if we don't try, we shall surely fail"?

Comment: I agree that it's definitely worth asking.

Comment: Nobody? Too bad!

Answer (score 2):

This was a very tough sell. Even the [Stack Overflow meetups](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/stack-overflow-meetups-april-6/) with millions of potential participants, it was hard to reach a critical mass of attendees.

Bicycles SE is a smaller site to begin with; plus, organizing it through the even-smaller meta site makes it more difficult (i.e. this post only had 34 views total).

**The way to pull this off** is to arrange a meetup around an existing, more popular event that might already have participants from this community. If there was an big-city ride or a trade show or other event, you could arrange a "meetup" of user who are already inclined to attend.

Comment: Summer Streets will be held in August, probably a good event to do this with. And Bicycles is a pretty small site as well. Nothing ventured, and all that. :)

Comment: @Neil Fain: When the event gets closer, let us know if there is anything we can do to help. We have are able to provide resources like funding, merchandise (t-shirts, stickers), etc... and anything else that would help these activities to be more productive and successful.

Comment: Bicycles.SE t-shirts might be pretty cool. Will contact you offline.